# With protractor and TypeScript, how can I return the column index of a grid based on the header text for that column?

Tags: typescript, protractor, webstorm

I'm trying to write a function that will return the column index of a grid, based on the header text for that column.  I've made numerous attempts, which appear in the comments below. In the end, this function always returns -1 instead of the expected column index.  With the WebStorm debugger I've been able to verify that the parameters entering the function are being populated.

Additionally, you can see one of my attempts at just doing this via a CSS selector, which was a desperation approach.

```
public getColumnIndexByHeaderText(gridId: string, headerText: string): number {
    var GRID_HEADER_REPEATER: string = 'col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid';
    var columnIndex: number = -1;

    // Attempt A
    element(by.id(gridId)).all(by.repeater(GRID_HEADER_REPEATER)).getText().then(function (textArray) {
        columnIndex = textArray.indexOf(headerText);
    });

    // Attempt B
    element(by.id(gridId)).then(function (grid) {
        grid.all(by.repeater(GRID_HEADER_REPEATER)).getText().then(function (textArray) {
            columnIndex = textArray.indexOf(headerText);
        });
    });

    // Attempt C
    element.all(by.repeater(GRID_HEADER_REPEATER)).filter(function (elm, index) {
        return elm.getText().then(function (text) {
            if (text === headerText) {
                return index;
            }
        });
    });

    // Attempt D
    var cssSelector = '#' + gridId + ' .ui-grid-header span.ng-binding';
    element.all(by.css(cssSelector)).getText().then(function (textArray) {
        columnIndex = textArray.indexOf(headerText);
    });

    return columnIndex;
};
```

Other approaches that I tried (not shown here) also failed.  It feels like I'm just overlooking something fundamental.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with a colleague, he pointed out a couple of salient problems with the approach that I took above.  He was able to fix this as follows:

First, the signature for the function needed to return a promise, not a number. Note the return type and the return statements.

```
public getIndexByHeaderText(gridId: string, headerText: string): protractor.promise.Promise<number> {
    var GRID_HEADER_REPEATER: string = 'col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid';
    return element(by.id(gridId)).all(by.repeater(GRID_HEADER_REPEATER)).getText().then(function (textArray) {
        return textArray.indexOf(headerText);
    });
};
```

Second, the call to this function needs to treat it as a promise, and assign the returned value via the then-function syntax, like so.

```
it('Should do something', function() {
    lib.grid.getRow.byRowIdentifier(page.GRID_ID, newUserEmailPrefix, 'name').then(function (gridReturnObject) {
        lib.grid.column.getIndexByHeaderText(page.GRID_ID, 'Header Text').then(function (columnIndex) {
            var deactivateButtonCell = gridReturnObject.rowCellElements[columnIndex];
            // Other code omitted for clarity...
        });
    });
});
```